# The largest number listed below which is less than $\sqrt {10020}-\sqrt {10010}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The largest number listed below which is less than
>   $\sqrt {10020}-\sqrt {10010}$ ?
>
> (a) $10$ (b) $1$ (c) $1/10$ (d) $1/20$ (e) $1/40$

Comment: Hint: rationalize the numerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$=\dfrac{10020-10010}{\sqrt{10020}+\sqrt{10010}}$$ as $100^2=?<10010<10020<101^2$

So, $100<\sqrt{10010}<\sqrt{10020}<101$

Comment: You need to have the inequality to the other side to show that it's indeed $>1/40$ to know that e is the correct answer.

Comment: @skyking, please find the latest version

Comment: Got it , Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$[\sqrt{10020}-\sqrt{10010}]×$

$\dfrac {\sqrt{10020}+\sqrt{10010}}{\sqrt{10020} + \sqrt{10010}}.$

Numerator= $10$;

Denominator $\gt  2×100$.

Fraction $\lt 10/(200).$

Answer?

Comment: E    ,  Thank you very much

Comment: Prayer. Welcome.Glad it helped. Any more?:)))